# Maven GroupID and ArtifactID for J2EE Utility Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, naming-conventions

I have a collection of 3 existing Eclipse projects that I want to make into Maven projects and I'm having a hard time understanding the relationship between the GroupID, ArtifactID and my Java Packaging, and the different directory structure that is created for Maven vs. Java projects. I'm pretty new to J2EE and completely new to Maven, so any advice is welcome! Let me describe my projects first.

The first project is IDMU_JAR. The base Java packaging is com.foo.util.merge and it contains Java classes like Template and Bookmark and the target jar file is com.foo.util.merge.jar

The second project is IDUM_WAR. The base class in this project is com.foo.util.merge.web and it references the IDMU_JAR project and contains only a few Servlets that expose the functionality in IDMU_JAR.

The third project is IDMU_EAR. Currently this is just a device for creating a deployment EAR that contains IDMU_JAR, WAR and it's dependencies.

My questions are:

Is my J2EE packaging and naming "typical" or have I already gone against best practices?

Am I better off creating the Maven Project and then converting it to a Faceted project and picking the facets, or should I be creating the Java Utility/WAR/EAR projects and then converting them to Maven projects?

This appears to have a big impact on the directory structure of the project, is this important?.

Does my Eclipse Project name have to match the Maven Artifact ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure pretty much anything in maven from file structure to project special configuration. But If it's not absolutly necessery you should stick with maven defaults.

You can start with that project template:
[javaee-essentials-pom](https://github.com/ecabrerar/javaee-essentials-pom)

For the project namings:

GroupID: com.foo

ArtifactID: idmu-utils, idmu-war, idmu-ear

package: jar, war, ear

With Eclipse:

Start by using the template I provided. Importing as maven project from Eclipse should resolve all facets available automatically.

Comment: If my fully qualified name is deeper than com.foo.... com.foo.util.merge is the Java package, would my GroupID be com.foo.util or com.foo.util.merge?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to maven. I'm assuming that I should start with a mvn archetype:generate command rather than using the Eclipse - New Maven Project wizard. How do I leverage the javaee-essentials-pom you have linked.... I've tried specifying it as -DarchetypeArtifactId=javaee-essentials-pom on the mvn generate command, but that is obviously not the correct way to do it... do I just clone the git-hub project down to my machine? If so, where should it go relative to maven/bin?

Comment: Start by cloning it.
The GroupID is a logical identifier and is only used to organize your own packages, So the GroupId could be the same for all your packages.

Your GroupID can be more complexe according to the maven convention https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I think I should also mention that I have an existing GitHub project for the source (https://github.com/FlatBallFlyer/IBM-Data-Merge-Utility) - please keep in mind that I am not a professional Java developer, just a hack trying to get something done the right way. The v3 Beta release packaging is the Eclipse default. My plan is 1. Generate a fresh Maven project 2. Copy my source into it. 3. Import that into a fresh eclipse workspace and test, 4. Copy that structure to git folder. 5. Re-test and publish. How far off am I? Can you suggest Open Source publishing howto?

Comment: Ok, a bit off topic but here is my suggestion:

1. clone the template I provided with git, and delete unnecessary parts (appclient,ejb,wsappclient)

2. commit the template in a new branch (example:mavenBeta.v3)

3. copy your code in that branch and change in every pom.xml the artifactid, groupid,etc...

4. push that branch in your github

5. try it in Eclipse

Comment: I'm a bit thick, am I supposed to commit the javaee-essentials-pom project to a branch of my existing project? I'm confused as to the relationship between my existing github project and the clone of javaee-essentials-pom

Comment: Your project is a ear, a war and a jar. The template is a ear, a war and a ejb change the ejb for a jar and you have the same structure. An ejb is essentially a jar with bean features.